# Geoserver Realm

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I have been trying for the past fews days to create a GIS app with Geoext, Openlayers and Geoserver through Apache!

Well I achieved that but I had created many users with different roles!

When I am loading my app Mozilla or Chrome etc asks for Geoserver Realm "Username" and Password"! Actually is this what I need but I want to have a login and logout button somewhere to my app to change users!

Unfortunately, I am finding a lot of answers about users, security and authentication but I can't understand how actually I can do it works!

Can you please help me?